# Upgrade PHP mysql code to use mysqli instead

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a site written in PHP with sql code, what is the best way to upgrade my code to sqli? any training or tutorials? how to have clear PHP code?

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("timer");
```

Comment: If you look at rewriting anyway, why not use [PDO](http://de2.php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) - even more future-proof and gives you added flexibility, since exchanging db will be done easily...  (Upps, STT LCU beat me - sry for repeating, my typing is too slow...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation touches that, to some extent, e.g. [here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php). You can use the same function names, just prefixed with `mysqli` instead of `mysql` for the most part, apparently.

From there you should be able to swap out parts of your code with better constructs in `mysqli`, e.g. parametrised statements instead of manually concatenating SQL.

Comment: just start writing with sqli? no change or something needed?

Comment: Well, you cannot use a connection started with `mysql_connect` with `mysqli_query`, so you have to upgrade all places at once. But apart from that the procedural interface seems to be largely the same.

Comment: and could you tell me what is the difference? why sqli preferred?

Comment: There is a [feature matrix](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) in the documentation. Short story is that the `mysql` extension is old, clunky and doesn't support newer features in the server at all. I suspect a large reason why they didn't just improve the `mysql` extension is backwards compatibility and the large risk of breaking pretty much everything out there.